# dotnet watch broken in mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am new to dotnet and I was using dotnet watch to develop my code on Mac. I got it to run but when the Visual Studio restarted, it just stopped working.

The program that I was working on uses the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 but the dotnet watch uses ASPNetCore 8.0.3. I deleted the version 8.0.3 in the `/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` folder and after I run the dotnet watch it was able to run just fine. But when I restarted the Visual Studio, it was using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App on this folder `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/8.0.1/libexec/shared`. So I deleted the 8.0.3 folder.

After that it just keeps on looking at this folder and won't run dotnet watch at all.

I don't know how to force it to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 again.

Comment: "I deleted ..." is what you should never do again. The standard ways are 1) use `global.json` to force `dotnet` CLI to use .NET 6 SDK, 2) or simply uninstall .NET 8 SDK and use .NET 6 SDK. Now your manual changes leave the system inconsistent, and no one can easily help you out. BTW, I don't think Microsoft support .NET bits from Homebrew (at least not from the download page https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0).